# How Can i get latest version of QuickFix Protocol for crypto currency in CPP

Tags: cryptography, bitcoin, quickfix

Kindly let me know where Can I  get latest version of "QuickFix Protocol" for crypto currency in Cpp

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

QuickFIX is not a protocol.

**FIX** ("Financial Information eXchange") is the protocol.  QuickFIX is an open-source engine for communicating over that protocol.

FIX is not just for crypto.

Your question will surely get closed soon, because it's a bad question that doesn't meet StackOverflow's standards. Please attempt to do some internet searches and educate yourself, because someone who had actually tried to learn more would not ask a question this basic.